# Cell spacing and ConvertTo-Html Fragment

Tags: html, css, powershell

I have a ordered hashtable I am converting to HTML using the following code:

```
$VFront = $VPLEX_Front | % {
$cluster = $_ -split ' +'
$hash = [ordered]@{
  'Cluster Name'                = $cluster[0]
  'Total Storage Views'         = $cluster[1]
  'Unhealthy Storage Views'     = $cluster[2]
  'Total Registered Initiators' = $cluster[3]
  'Total Ports'                 = $cluster[4]
  'Total Exported Volumes'      = $cluster[5]
  'Total ITLs'                  = $cluster[6]
}
New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $hash
} | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

This table will be part of a much larger html report (table within a table if that matters). This works fine but the cells are a little to close for comfort. Here is the output:
[image]

I'd like to add some spacing between the columns so it is easier to read across.

I tried using -Head after ConvertTo-Html and setting a style with cell padding but it just printed the html code in plain text.

Comment: You cannot combine `-Head` and `-Fragment` parameters. They are from different parameter sets. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849944.aspx. Generates only an HTML table. Fragment: _The HTML, HEAD, TITLE, and BODY tags are omitted._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating fragment of HTML in your code above. If you look at the [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849944.aspx) article for `ConvertTo-HTML` you will see that you cannot combine -Head and -Fragment parameters as they are from different parameter sets.

Looking at the details for `-Fragment` on the same page reads

> Generates only an HTML table. Fragment: The HTML, HEAD, TITLE, and BODY tags are omitted.

**Possible Solution**

Not sure if this is the best caliber for an answer but you could edit the html text before you put it into its final location.

```
$html = $html -replace "\<table\>",'<table cellpadding="10">'
```

Where `$html` is the output from your code snippet. That will add some padding to the table which you could adjust as needed.

**Comparison**

First is obviously the example with the padding changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tag attributes (`<table cellpadding="10">`) shouldn't be used for formatting anymore in this day and age. Use CSS instead. You can insert your table fragment into an HTML template like this:

```
@"
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type='text/css'>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
$VFront
</body>
</html>
"@ | Out-File 'C:\path\to\your.html'
```

**Examples:**

Table with `padding: 0;`:

[image]

Table with `padding: 5px;`:

[image]

You can do other funky stuff with CSS too, like alternating row colors:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgray;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
}
```

[image]